# Очередность ходов в крестиках ноликах

Tags: c++, qt

Делаю крестики нолики на qt,не могу придумать как сделать чтоб крестики и нолики ставились по очереди,помогите,пожалуйста

Comment: подсказка - Вам нужна дополнительная переменная, где будет записываться текущий элемент - крестик или нолик. Но на самом деле можно воспользоваться тем, что номер хода как раз и показывает, что нужно отображать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самое красивое, на мой взгляд, решение будет использовать [машину состояний](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstatemachine.html). Вот, например, кнопка:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <QPushButton>
#include <QStateMachine>
#include <QSignalTransition>
#include <QAbstractState>
#include <QDebug>

class State : public QState{
    Q_OBJECT
    QString _name;
public:
    explicit State(const QString &name):
        _name(name)
    {}
signals:
    void entered(const QString &name);
protected:
    void onEntry(QEvent *event){
        emit entered(_name);
        QState::onEntry(event);
    }
};

class Test : public QPushButton{
    Q_OBJECT
    QStateMachine _machine;
public:
    Test(QWidget *parent = 0):
        QPushButton(parent)
    {
        State *x = new State("x");
        connect(x, SIGNAL(entered(QString)), this, SLOT(_setText(QString)));
        _machine.addState(x);

        State *o = new State("o");
        connect(o, SIGNAL(entered(QString)), this, SLOT(_setText(QString)));
        _machine.addState(o);

        x->addTransition(this, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), o);
        o->addTransition(this, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), x);

        _machine.setInitialState(x);
        _machine.start();
    }
private slots:
    void _setText(const QString &text){
        setText(text);
    }
};

#endif // TEST_H
```

Если на неё нажать, то произойдет переход из состояния `x` в состояние `o`, и текст на кнопке изменится.
Если вам не хочется заморачиваться с машиной состояний, того же эффекта можно добиться и другим путем:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVector>

class Strings{
    int _i;
    QVector<QString> _strings;
public:
    Strings():
        _i(0)
    {
        _strings.append("x");
        _strings.append("o");
    }
    const QString& next(){
        return _strings[_nextIndex()];
    }
private:
    int _nextIndex(){
        return _i++ % _strings.size();
    }
};

class Test : public QPushButton{
    Q_OBJECT
    Strings _strings;
public:
    Test(QWidget *parent = 0):
        QPushButton(parent)
    {
        connect(this, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(_setNextText()));
        _setNextText();
    }
private slots:
    void _setNextText(){
        setText(_strings.next());
    }
};

#endif // TEST_H
```

Он проще, но не такой красивый, и вы не сможете сказать своим друзьям, что в ваших крестиках-ноликах используется машина состояний